# CanvasJS chart with average of database column

Tags: php, canvasjs

This is my database:

[image: db]

I want to show the **average of each column** in a column chart, like this example https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/multiple-axis-column-chart/

So the average of PD1 in blue and of PD2 in red, SVK1 in blue, SVK2 in red and so on.

I've been trying to modify this example code: https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/chart-data-from-database/

but I can't get it to work. This is what I've tried

```
foreach ($link->query('Select AVG(PD1), AVG(PD2) from table') as $row) {
    $PD1 = $row['AVG(PD1)'];
    $PD2 = $row['AVG(PD2)'];
    array_push($dataPoints,"$PD1","$PD2");
    array_push($dataPoints2, array("y"=> $dataPoints));
};
```

Would be super grateful for help!

Comment: You should not foreach the query. You need to fetch it and then iterate over the fetched results.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you mean by "iterate over the fetched results".. :( 


`$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select AVG(PD1), AVG(PD2) from table");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); `


I do something like this and then still need a foreach loop? I'm really lost here :(

Comment: I am normally using prepare(), execute() and then fetch in a while loop. I did not know that I could 'query' it directly. Thanks for that! But I noticed the mistake. You can set custom 'column' names and refer to them in the results. See my answer below. Sorry for the circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

You can give custom labels on expressions and use those as key.

```php
foreach ($link->query('Select AVG(PD1) AS a1, AVG(PD2) AS a2 FROM table') as $row) {
    $PD1 = $row['a1'];
    $PD2 = $row['a2'];
    array_push($dataPoints,"$PD1","$PD2");
    array_push($dataPoints2, array("y"=> $dataPoints));
};
```

Comment: I've already tried that.. it just displays a blank page, no chart at all. When I print out $dataPoints2 it shows the correct average values, so it has something to do with how CanvasJS works